# SQLException - No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence.xml

I have a problem. I'm created EntityManager with credentials of Persistence.xml but I give message error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql/localhost:9999/DB".

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong, could you help me or give me advice on how to solve this problem, please. Thanks in advance.

The configurations that I use are:

Persistence.xml:

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="DB-dev">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.development.rrhh.model.entity.entity1</class>
    <class>com.development.rrhh.model.entity.entity2</class>
    ...
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_RRHH" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="developer" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="deve.951741" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

POM.xml

```
<project ...>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.1212.jre7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
       ....
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

JPAUtility.java

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class JPAUtility {

  private static final EntityManagerFactory EMF;

  static {
    EMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DB-dev");
  }

  public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return EMF.createEntityManager();
  }

  public static void close() {
    EMF.close();
  }

}
```

Error in log of JBoss:

```
22:55:52,806 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
22:55:52,811 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
22:55:52,815 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
22:55:52,818 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_RRHH]
22:55:52,821 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=developer, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
22:55:52,826 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_RRHH
22:55:52,830 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
22:55:52,832 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
22:55:52,835 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
22:55:52,838 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
22:55:52,863 WARN  [org.hibernate.ejb.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (development-dev-test) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
22:55:52,868 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
22:55:52,869 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_RRHH
22:55:52,872 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
22:55:52,875 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component UsuarioImpl for method public abstract com.development.rrhh.model.entity.Usuario com.development.rrhh.core.serv.UsuarioServ.find(java.lang.String) throws com.development.rrhh.exceptions.ServiceException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at com.development.rrhh.core.serv.UsuarioServ$$$view102.find(Unknown Source) [development-rrhh-core-1.0.0.jar:]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:508) [wicket-ioc-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.find(Unknown Source)
  at com.development.rrhh.session.SignIn$SignInForm.loadUser(SignIn.java:85) [classes:]
  at com.development.rrhh.session.SignIn$SignInForm.onSubmit(SignIn.java:56) [classes:]
  at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1316) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.StatelessForm.process(StatelessForm.java:100) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:708) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:241) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64) [wicket-request-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284) [wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:816) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:770) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at com.development.rrhh.core.impl.UsuarioImpl.find(UsuarioImpl.java:53) [development-rrhh-core-1.0.0.jar:]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:127) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:135) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:84) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
  ... 63 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1739) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:828) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2058) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:870) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:863) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:795) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  ... 91 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_RRHH
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
  at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:276) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
  ... 116 more
```

I'm using: Java 1.7, Jee7, JBoss 7.1.0 Final, Posgresql 9.5, Maven 3.3.9 and Wicket 7.9 (although the latter is not relevant to the problem).

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the `jar` to the `classpath` of your `jboss` server. There's a directory called `modules` where you can put your jars. This might help: [Install a Module in jBoss](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7)

Comment: If you mean to create the Postgresql JAR as a module, I created it on the Jboss server. But it still gives me that same error.

Comment: I followed the instructions of the link you sent me, but I still get the error: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: 
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_RRHH

Comment: The issue I can tell is that your server is not finding the class (`jar`).

Comment: @rodrixd were you able to address the issue. I have similar issue where I've installed Postgresql driver as module and also had the .jar inside .war. My JPA is not having any issues but for some reason we use the JDBC as well where it's throwing error saying no suitable driver found.